# Inserting a date variable into Dataframe with a sting file path (read.csv)

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am working through a process where I want to ingest a csv file into a Dataframe. This file is a delta file that runs daily and is stored in Azure DataLake store.

```
DF = (

  spark
  .read.option("header",True)\.option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv("folder2/folder1/Intenstion_file2020*.csv")
)
```

From the above code I basically collect all the files that start with "file2020" and then all other files. So if there is 10 then it gets put into one dataframe.

What I want to do through is instead of ingesting all of those 10 files into a dataframe is instead select the file that matches a system date. So if I have the following files:
​
​1) file2020/01/01
​2) file2020/01/02
​3) file2020/01/09
​
​I want only the third file to be ingested. Then the next time it would select the next file that has the most current date.

I tried solving this by first getting a system date. This runs before the dataframe portion.

```
 #Getting System Time Stamp
import datetime
date_value = datetime.datetime.now()
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(date_value,'%Y/%m/%d'))
```

So if I run that above notebook I would have "date_value" = 2020/01/09. What I wanted to do is then concatanate that value into the "csv(path)" in the dataframe example above.

So instead of having

```
.csv("folder2/folder1/Intenstion_file2020*.csv")
```

I would have something like:

```
.csv(concat_ws("....file" date_value "*.csv"))
```

So it would automatically find the file with the date that is closest to system date.

I tried some variables of above, but I am missing the proper syntax or if what I am doing above is possible. Has anyone tried to do the above?

Any help is appreciated.​

**Update 01/09/2020**
I updated the question to make it clearer as to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way you are using concat_ws is wrong.

Please refer this -
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws

And more over you cannot concatenate a column and string. It should be two columns.

So use f.concat_ws("-", df.colA, f.lit("date_value"))

Comment: Hi @pkatta, thanks for the post. The reason I was using concat is not because I had to, but what came to mind. I am open to other operations that would work. Sorry I am little confused by your solution. Would the concat_ws have to be used after the Dataframe reads the data from the csv file before being applying the date filter? 

I guess my problem is that I would want to filter out the old files before they would be read into the dataframe and I am not sure how to insert that date filter into the actual path string.

Comment: Sorry I was confused a little  1) I think you need to change the format like this '%Y%m%d' instead of this '%Y/%m/%d'. Looking at the code you wanted date in the following format "....file20191217*.csv"  2) You don't have to use concat_ws function you can simply do this 
now = (datetime.datetime.strftime(now,'%Y%m%d') 
.csv(file_name+str(now)+"xxx.csv")

Comment: Hi pkatta, thanks for replying, but I think I am still lost. What I am trying to do is create a dataframe that reads a file directly from an ADLS folder. Below is how I did it originally.

DF = (

  spark
  .read.option("header",True).option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv("folder1/folder2/CSV_file_01082019.csv") 
)

The problem is that instead of "01082019" (which is a string) I want to insert the date variable I called "now". 

So what would happen is that the Dataframe "DF" would automatiically choose file that is equal to system date.